# AWS Athena - MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

We recently attached our MongoDB to Athena. However, we are not able to correctly query

Here is a snippet of the structure and associated query that I am trying to run.  This table has lot of other columns.  But below structure shows and array that structure in it.

```
{
  "legal_names": [
    {
      "Legal_Name": "string",
      "ORG": "string",
      "MERCHANT_NUMBER": "double"
    }
  ]
}
```

SELECT n.ORG FROM "aslanss"."entities" cross join UNNEST("aslanss"."entities"."Legal_Names") as t(n) limit 10

The error we get is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7VgP.png)

Here is a snippet of the structure and associated query that I am trying to run

"Error  while processing field Legal_Names

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRv9a.png)

SELECT n.ORG FROM "aslanss"."entities" cross join UNNEST("aslanss"."entities"."Legal_Names") as t(n) limit 10

The error we get is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7VgP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Athena accepts mixed cases in DDL and DML queries but lowercases the names when it executes the query. For this reason, please don't use mixed case for table or column names, and do not rely on casing alone in Athena to distinguish such names. For example, if you use a DDL statement to create a column named Castle, the column created will be lowercased to castle. If you then specify the column name in a DML query as Castle or CASTLE, Athena will lowercase the name for you to run the query, but display the column heading using the casing that you chose in the query.

So in your case, I see the col name specified is mixed case, I suggest you only use lower case for table names and table column names in Athena

[Use lower case for table names and table column names in Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-databases-columns-names.html#table-names-and-table-column-names-in-ate-must-be-lowercase)